# Get data based on latest date

Tags: tableau-api

Based on the dataset below, I'm trying to get the lastest cost based on the latest report date.

For example: When the report date=forecast date (column headers) then pick the values as on that report date which can be achived by this formula

```
IF [Report Date]=[Forecast Date] THEN [Forecasted Cost] END
```

but I also want to get the subsequent values as of the lastest report date i.e. 2/15/2019. How do I achieve this?

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|            | 8/15/2018 | 9/15/2018 | 10/15/2018 | 11/15/2018 | 12/15/2018 | 1/15/2019 | 2/15/2019 | 3/15/2019 | 4/15/2019 | 5/15/2019 | 6/15/2019 | 7/15/2019 | 8/15/2019 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Final Cost |  646.00   |  646.00   |  620.00    |  620.00    |  550.00    |  445.00   |  361.00   |  332.50   |  315.40   |  296.40   |  290.70   |  285.00   |  279.30   |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**DATASET**

```
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Item | Report Date | 8/15/2018 | 9/15/2018 | 10/15/2018 | 11/15/2018 | 12/15/2018 | 1/15/2019 | 2/15/2019 | 3/15/2019 | 4/15/2019 | 5/15/2019 | 6/15/2019 | 7/15/2019 | 8/15/2019 |
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 4124 | 8/15/2018   |  646.00   |  646.00   |  658.00    |  658.00    |  658.00    |  658.00   |  658.00   |           |           |           |           |           |           |
| 4124 | 9/15/2018   |           | 646       | 626        | 626        | 626        | 622       | 622       | 622       |           |           |           |           |           |
| 4124 | 10/15/2018  |           |           | 620        | 620        | 620        | 585       | 585       | 585       | 555       |           |           |           |           |
| 4124 | 11/15/2018  |           |           |            | 620        | 620        | 610       | 595       | 554.5     | 543.38    | 535.35    |           |           |           |
| 4124 | 12/15/2018  |           |           |            |            | 550        | 535       | 505       | 490       | 490       | 490       | 490       |           |           |
| 4124 | 1/15/2019   |           |           |            |            |            | 445       | 430       | 420       | 410       | 400       | 390       |       384 |           |
| 4124 | 2/15/2019   |           |           |            |            |            |           | 361       | 332.5     | 315.4     | 296.4     | 290.7     |       285 | 279.3     |
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to transpose your dataset, i.e. to have 4 columns "Item", "Report Date", "Forecast Date" and "Forecast Cost". Then you create a filter "forecast date >= report date" and show values by forecast date. 
Now you will have multiple values for each forecast date. if you only want to get the latest value, then you can use table calculation window_min(date diff).

Comment: "Pivot", not transpose